# Опрос состояния компьютера через WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

Нужна помощь или подсказка в какую сторону копать. Хочу написать приложение для ПК(серверная часть) с клиентом под андроид. Нашел информацию про WCF. Но не понимаю как реализовать нужный мне функционал. На компьютере хосте я отслеживаю запущен ли браузер или нет (периодически получаю список запущенных приложении). На клиент должно прийти уведомление, что браузер запустился. Прочитал про callback но или я не до конца понял или все же так и есть. С точки зрения WCF Service Contract это доступный функционал от сервиса клиенту а Callback это то, что доступно для сервиса от клиента. И как в таком случае реализовать нужный мне функционал? Что бы сервис сам отправлял нужные данные клиенту.

Comment: См. [Создание дуплексного контракта](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-duplex-contract).

Comment: а не слишком ли **жырно**  для отслеживания запущенного браузера целый wcf разворачивать? IIS поднимать таки надо... Может через windows-сервис с отправкой обычного емэйла, как вариант. Ну или Powershell c шедулером... Да хоть snmp в конце-концов.

Comment: @defrag зачем IIS если wcf службу можно хостить в консольном приложении? Да и данное приложение это всего лишь попытка понять, как передавать данные от сервиса к клиенту.

Comment: точно, совсем забыл про хостинг в консольном приложении. Но если это все для `попытки понять`, то вопросов нет :]